# Fiddler: can I disable SSL session renegotiation

Tags: ssl, fiddler

Well, the title says it all. For testing purposes I need that each SSL session will renegotiate its encryption parameters. Can I configure Fiddler in such a way to always decline a client's request to reuse previously negotiated encryption params, and force it to negotiate new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't know any way to force SChannel (the stack under System.Net.Security's HTTPS implementation) to do that.

One quick thing to remember is that when you have HTTPS decryption enabled there are two HTTPS connections in this scenario-- one from the client to Fiddler and one from Fiddler to the server.